# Theorem about fractional iterated functions : is it true, and if yes has it already been discovered?

Tags: limits, functions

So, I've been playing with tetration for quite a while now, and I've noticed the method I've been using can possibly be used in any other iteration of a function that satisfy this condition :

$f(+\infty)$ converges to a finite value.
For clarification, $f^n(x) = f(f(f(...x)))$ n times.

So here's the theorem :
for any function $f$ where $f^n(x)$ equals the nth iteration of $f(x)$, where $n$ is a integer, and that the infinite iteration of $f$ equals a finite value $\tau$, $$f^k(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}(f^{-n}((f^n(x)-\tau)f'(\tau)^k +\tau))$$ for any complex number $k$ if $f'(\tau)$ doesn't equal $1$ or $0$.

I've noticed that in this case, the ratio between $\frac{f^{n+1}(x)-\tau}{f^{n}(x)-\tau}$ ALWAYS approaches $f'(\tau)$ when $n$ approaches $+\infty$, no matter what. So because we have a ratio, we can then calculate the $(n+k)$th iteration of the function, and by taking the proper amount of time the inverse function, we can have the nth iteration of the function.

If the function approaches $\tau$ from the top or bottom, the ratio is positive, if it ocilates around $\tau$, it's negative, meaning the kth iteration will often result in complex results.

So is this true? (I'm unable to demonstrate it), and if it is, has it already been discovered?

Comment: Just for the sake of clarity: 1. What are you assuming about $f$? You use $f^{-n}$; does that mean $f$ is invertible? Also, are we assuming $f$ is differentiable everywhere (presuming $f'$ is the derivative)? 2. Does $f(+\infty)$ refer to $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$? Similarly, what does the "infinite iteration of $f$" mean? Do you mean $\lim_{n \to \infty} f(x)$ for some $x$? If so, which $x$? Or are we assuming that this quantity is always constant with respect to $x$?

Comment: While answering Theo's question (preferrably by editing your question), could you possible also say what is meant by $f^n$? It seems you are using this notation for $f\circ f\cdots \circ f$ ($f$ $n$ times iterated), and not for the $n$th power of $f(x)$ (?).

Comment: Well, theo. $f^{-n}(x)$ means iterating nth times the inverse function of $f$. I guess $f$ should be differenciable at least around $\tau$ such that $f'(\tau)$ exists. And what I mean by the infinite iteration of $f$ means for any starting x (well at best for any x, if not well we'll need to define the interval in which x belongs) applying infinitely many times $f$ converges. Like for the function $f(x) = \sqrt{x}$ the infinite iteration of $f$ equals 1 for any x. Like $\sqrt{(\sqrt{(\sqrt{(...x)})})}=1$

Comment: @PierreCarlier Thank you for clearing that up!

Comment: Sorry, one more question: what does $f'(\tau)^k$ mean? Does that mean the value of $f'(\tau)$ raised to the $k$th power? Or are we iterating $f'$ $k$ times on $\tau$, or something like that?

Comment: Ok adam. I'll fix the title

Comment: Theo, here I put the k at the right of the parenthesis, meaning raising $f'(\tau)$ to the kth power. If I meant to iterate $k$ times the derivative of $f$, I'll have written $f'^{k}(x)$

Comment: Could you please edit the question to include all the clarifications you've stated in the comments? People should not have to hunt through the comments to figure out what the heck you mean. And if you answered Theo Bendit's question about $f(+\infty)$, I cannot see it. It is unclear to me because you do not seem to make any reference to $\lim_{x \to \infty} f(x)$ anywhere else after requiring it to be finite.

Comment: Ok, I'll do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is known as Koenigs function, or at least equivalent.

$$f^k(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}(f^{-n}((f^n(x)-\tau)f'(\tau)^k +\tau))$$

(Recenter the fixpoint $\tau$ to zero if you want).

$$f^k(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}(f^{-n}((f^n(x)-\tau)f'(\tau)^k +\tau)) =  \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}(f^{-n+m}((f^n(x)-\tau)f'(\tau)^{k-m} +\tau))$$

For positive $m$ and $n$ sufficiently large.

Now let $m = n$

$$f^k(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}(f^{0}((f^n(x)-\tau)f'(\tau)^{k-n} +\tau))$$

$$f^0 = id(x)$$

So we get

$$f^k(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}(f^n(x)-\tau)f'(\tau)^{k-n} +\tau$$

See :

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koenigs_function

Notice how your formula is based on approximating with a taylor expansion, well linear approximation at least.
Your ratio ALWAYS approaching the derivative comes from that.

Although your limit is essentially the same as Koenigs, I did not study the convergeance speed and that may depend on $f$ itself.

My mentor currently studies iterating functions without a real fixpoint (such as $exp(x)$) and functions that converge to a constant at infinity such as $tanh(A x)$.

You might like this to do dynamics

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carleman_matrix

---

***edit***

Pierre's rediscovered formula is faster than Koenigs function.

Notice a few things.

1. the number of iterations is twice as much for Pierre's formula compared to Koenigs ; iterating both $f$ and $f^{-1}$ the same amount $n$ times. So we actually use $2n$ iterations.
2. Koenings only uses $n$ iterations and less than $n$ multiplications.
   It uses $n-k$ multiplications and for $0<k<n$ this implies less than $n$ multiplications.
3. The multiplications of koenings play the role of iterations but by linear approximations of the function iterated. Thus much less precise and hence lower convergeance speed.

From those observations we clearly see that Pierre's formula MUST converge faster.

If we want to study the convergeance we should better compare

$$f^k(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}(f^{-n}((f^n(x)-\tau)f'(\tau)^k +\tau))$$

versus

$$f^k(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}(f^{2n}(x)-\tau)f'(\tau)^{k-2n} +\tau$$

Or something like that.

Notice that $x$ near the fixpoint is better approximated by the linear than far away,so both $x$ and $n$ matter for the convergeance speed comparison.

Probably the second derivative matters alot.

In fact we could improve Koenings with a degree 2 approximation instead of the degree 1 now used.
That would make the race more exciting I think.
If we that the third derivative matters alot I guess.

Feel free to investigate and let me know what you found.

I hope this clarified some things.

Comment: Personally, as I've seen, my formula converges way faster and better. It highly depends on lambda, the closer to 0 the better. But thanks for your answer. I'm still glad I figured it out almost all by myself. The question I'm wondering is, my formula is mathematically correct and demonstrated, does that means that the definition of fractional iterated functions can officially be that? Since it could solve problems such as tetration. And could you ask your mentor about all of that? Thanks

Comment: To make it converge quicker (using the recursive properties of such functions) plus the fact nothing forbids us to use complex numbers (I checked it works), the current "modern" formula is   $$f^{\circ r+bi}(x) = \lim_{n \rightarrow + \infty} (f^{\circ \lfloor{r}\rfloor -n}((f^{\circ n}(x)-\tau)\lambda^{r-\lfloor{r}\rfloor + bi} + \tau))$$

Comment: Also there's some restriction about the number x. $[A,B]$ is the monotomic interval that contains $\tau$. if lambda is positive, for it to work $A<x<f(x)<\tau<B$ or $A<\tau<f(x)<x<B$. If lambda is negative, $A<x<f(f(x))<\tau<f(x)<B$ or $A<f(x)<\tau<f(f(x))<x<B$. Actually x can equal A or B as long as the other iterations aren't.

Comment: That assures x converges and all positive iterations stays inside the monotonic interval. Cause otherwise, if $f^n(x)$ doesn't belong to it, $f^{-1}(f(f^n(x)))≠f^n(x)$ where $f^{-1}$ is the inverse of $f$ in $[A,B]$

Comment: Wait a sec you're in the tetration forum?! Me too. Shanghai46

Comment: @PierreCarlier No I am not. But im familiar with it. My mentor tommy1729 is.

Comment: I see. Well nice to hear

Comment: @PierreCarlier SEE EDIT !

Comment: Do you accept my answer ? Is there anything else you want to know that directly relates to this ? Feel free to tag me for related questions if you start a related new question.

Comment: @PierreCarlier Thanks. If your function is analytic around your fixpoint and your fixpoint is not parabolic it gives a taylor series with nonzero radius. Im not sure what you had in mind ? What example ? I am only here.  But maybe you can invite me to a chat room

Comment: What I have in mind is with complex iterations. I'm retty sure that among the reals, my extention is continuous, unless the real negative integer iterations (calculated by the inverse function) aren't. (vertical asymptotes, into complex, etc). And how does a chatroom works?

Comment: @PierreCarlier https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/146600/fixpoint-methods

Comment: @PierreCarlier koenigs function does work for negative iterations. Ofcourse inverse functions can have branches and stuff !!
( You mentioned that in chat )
It is however not designed for that, as most methods are not.

Check out tommy's recent post at the forum, it might interest you. 
Sorry the chat was auto closed due to inactivity. Forgive my absense, have a nice day