# Iterating $\tanh(A x)$ and $\lim_{x \to +\infty} \tanh^{[r]}(A x) = C_r$?

Tags: asymptotics, hyperbolic-functions, tetration, complex-dynamics

Everybody who ever studied special relativity or hyperbolic trig knows this function

$$\tanh(Ax)$$

for real $0 < A < 1$

$\tanh(A x)$ has a nice attracting fixpoint at $0$ and it is asymptotic to a positive constant ($1$) for large positive $x$.
It is also strictly increasing.

So this is very well suited to do complex dynamics on it.

So we consider $r$ iterations :

$$\tanh^{[r]}(A x)$$

for $r > 0$.

$$\tanh^{[0]}(A x) = x$$
$$\tanh^{[1]}(A x) = \tanh(A x)$$
$$\tanh^{[r+1]}(A x) = \tanh(A \tanh^{[r]}(A x))$$

Notice for every such $r$ (and fixed $A$)

$$\lim_{x \to +\infty} \tanh^{[r]}(A x) = \lim_{x \to 1/A} \tanh^{[r-1]}(A x) = C_r$$

!!Keep in mind!!: $$\tanh^{[r-1]}(1) \neq \lim_{x \to 1/A} \tanh^{[r-1]}(A x)$$

(because $A$ belongs to the part of the function that we iterate.)

Where $C$ is a constant depending on $r$.

I want to understand this for $0<A<1$.

Let us agree to use koenigs function around the fixpoint $0$ to generate the iterations or anything equivalent to that.

Then how does $C_r$ behave asymptotically ?

I added the tag tetration because it is a rational function of $\exp(x)$ afterall, hope that is ok.

See here :
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Koenigs_function

See also this here what is essentially equal to koenigs, but might converge at at different speed :

[Theorem about fractional iterated functions : is it true, and if yes has it already been discovered?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4547564/theorem-about-fractional-iterated-functions-is-it-true-and-if-yes-has-it-alre)

$$f^k(x) = \lim_{n\rightarrow+\infty}(f^{-n}((f^n(x)-\tau)f'(\tau)^k +\tau))$$

Comment: By $\lim \tanh^{[r]}(A x) = C_r$ do you mean "$\tanh^{[r]}(A x) \sim C_r$ as $r\to+\infty$"?

Comment: $\lim \tanh^{[r]}(A x) = C_r$? Over which variable is the limit taken?

Comment: If $x\to +\infty$ then $C_r = \tanh^{[r-1]}(1)$. Are you sure that is your question?

Comment: The function is that is iterated (applied repeatedly) is $\tanh(.) $ or $\tanh(A .) ? $

Comment: It could be made clearer, but in the context, it is iterates of $x\to\tanh(Ax)$.

Comment: I made an edit to make things clear